# What is the condition of real eigen values other than symmetric matrix?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, mathematics

I have some difficulty to solve this question:[image]

What is the condition for real eigen values other than symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 2):

A graphical method is to find the characteristic equation and then determine the threshold values using the root locus plot.

Here are the calculations using Mathematica. The largest value is 5.75.

[image]

Comment: Suba good answer. I used rlocusplot in Matlab and basically got the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

At the bifurcation between all real eigenvalues and one pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues there has to be a duplicate real eigenvalue. So the characteristic polynomial of the matrix at the bifurcation should be of the following form

$$
(\lambda - a)^2(\lambda - b)(\lambda - c) = 
\lambda^4 - \left(2\,a + b + c\right)\,\lambda^3 + \left(2\,a\,(b + c) + b\,c + a^2\right)\,\lambda^2 - \left(a^2\,(b + C) + 2\,a\,b\,c\right)\,\lambda + a^2\,b\,c.
$$

The actual characteristic polynomial of the matrix can be shown to be equal to

$$
\det(\lambda\,I - A) = \lambda^4 + 0\,\lambda^3 - 15\,\lambda^2 + 10\,\lambda + 24 + \alpha.
$$

So in order for these two to be equal the following is required

$$
\begin{align}
2\,a + b + c &= 0 \\
2\,a\,(b + c) + b\,c + a^2 &= -15 \\
a^2\,(b + c) + 2\,a\,b\,c &= -10 \\
a^2\,b\,c &= 24 + \alpha
\end{align}
$$

simplifying these equations gives

$$
\begin{align}
b + c &= -2\,a \\
b\,c &= 3\,a^2 - 15 \\
2\,a^3 - 15\,a + 5 &= 0 \\
3\,a^2\,(a^2 - 5) &= 24 + \alpha
\end{align}
$$

In order for $b$ and $c$ to be real it can be shown that it is required that $2\,a^2 < 15$ and for $\alpha$ to be positive it is required that $2\,a^2 > 5 + \sqrt{57}$. By checking the roots of the cubic equation in $a$ against these constraints and using those can be used to solve for $\alpha$.